# Can a cookie stored locally (in a browser) see my browsing history?

Tags: cookies, browser

Can cookies see my browsing history in a browser? I.e. for example say I visit facebook, does facebook know what pages I've visited before?

I.e. is it necessary to delete browsing history for fear that cookies might acquire it somehow and learn about my browsing habits or sites I often visit?

And do they have access to my bookmarks?

Comment: Cookies pieces of are data. They can't "do" anything.

Comment: Cookies are used to record data that the user enters right? Now can this data be browsing history? For example recording pages that the user visits in other tabs?

Comment: Take for example: try looking online for a specific item (say a wallet), then visit amazon; you'll see how wallet ads will start popping up.

Comment: @latach: You're misunderstanding what cookies are.  Cookies are data.  That's like asking whether paper can see your pen.  A cookie can hold anything the server puts in it.

Comment: So how does this happen? (please see my second comment right above yours @SLaks)

Comment: Because sites that you clicked on in that search had ads or tracking pixels that set cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are small pieces of information websites can store in your browser. Cookies can also identify you and track your browsing activity across a website. The 3rd party cookies are used for advertising networks to track your usage across different websites.So if 2 websites that you visited uses same advertising network then your browsing data across both the sites can be linked.
Another example is if any website has facebook like button and you liked,then facebook knows you visited that site.

Answer (score 1):

So the direct short answer to my question is: No.

Explanation is: No, cookies do not have access to my browsing history, unless it was a third-party cookie that has to meet conditions specified here (a website 'A' can track other websites that host ads about 'A'):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Third-party_cookie

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As far as cookies go, they can only be written and read by the same website domain.  Cookies belong to a site.

So if you visited Facebook, theoretically, Facebook could write to a cookie of the Facebook page you were on.  And each time you clicked around FB, it could update / append this cookie with that page history.

But if you then went to Twitter, Twitter could not read (or write to) the same cookie Facebook wrote to.